# Upper-bound $\sup_{x \ne 0}\dfrac{\sum_i \lambda_i x_i^2}{\sum_i \sigma_i x_i^2}$, where $\lambda_1 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_n > 0$ (same with $\sigma$)

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, quadratic-forms, upper-lower-bounds, svd

Let $\lambda_1 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_n > 0$ and $\sigma_1 \ge \ldots \ge \sigma_n > 0$ and for nonzero $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$, define the quotient
$$
R(x) := \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i x_i^2}.
$$

> **Question.** What is a good upper-bound for $R^* := \sup_{x \in \mathbb R^n,\;x \ne 0}R(x)$ ?

**Trivial bound.** It is easy to see that $R^* \le \lambda_1/\sigma_n$, but this bound is really bad, as can be seen when $\lambda_i=\sigma_i$ for all $i$. Indeed, this trivial bound predicts $R^* \le \lambda_1/\lambda_d$ which can be arbitrarily larger than the actual value of $1$.

> **Question 1.** What if $\lambda_i = \sigma_i$ for all $i \ge k$ (where $k \le n$ is fixed), is there a good upper-bound for $R^*$ as a function of $k$ and the $\lambda$'s and $\sigma$'s ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By scaling the vector $x$, we may assume
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_ix_i^2=1,$$
and we want to maximize
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_ix_i^2.$$
Substituting $y_i=\sqrt{\sigma_i}x_i$, we have $\sum y_i^2=1$ and want to optimize
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\lambda_i}{\sigma_i}\right)y_i^2.$$
This is at most
$$\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\frac{\lambda_i}{\sigma_i}\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2=\max_{1\leq i\leq n}\frac{\lambda_i}{\sigma_i},$$
and equality is reached by one of the elementary vectors ($1$ in one component and $0$ in all others). So, the optimum is $\max \lambda_i/\sigma_i$.

Comment: Thanks! Elegant and simple. And as the saying goes, "I should have thought of that!"

Comment: @dohmatob You're welcome! If you're interested, this is basically just writing the problem as maximizing the operator norm of a particular matrix, here the diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda_i/\sigma_i$. If you have intervening $x_ix_j$ terms, you can still find similar bounds by determining the eigenvalues of a properly-chosen matrix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use
$$\min_i \frac{a_i}{b_i} \le \frac{\sum_i a_i}{\sum_i b_i}\le \max_i \frac{a_i}{b_i}$$
( $b_i$ positive)

Comment: Interesting. Indeed, this gives the nontrivial upper-bound $R^* \le \max_{i}\lambda_i/\sigma_i$, in one line!